# Bootstrap 3 typeahead - remote url never called

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm using typeahead with bootstrap 3 and I've written these:

test.php

```
<?php
 class names {
 var $name;

  function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }   
}   

$data=array();
$data['aaData'] = array();
foreach (array('kiki','dries','wolf') as $name) {
  $data['aaData'][] = new names($name); 
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

and I've written this script:

```
$('#attivita').typeahead({
            name : 'resultArticle',
            remote : {
             url: 'test.php?query=%QUERY',
             filter: function(data) {
                 console.log("doesn't log here");
                 var resultList = data.aaData.map(function (item) {
                 return item.name;
             });
             console.log(resultList);
             return resultList;
           }
        }
       });
```

the html code is:

```
<input type="text" name="attivita" id="attivita" class="campi-form typeahead" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead"/>
```

The autocomplete doesn't work, maybe I've written a wrong url because the log in the function of filter attribute is never written and I notice that if I copy the url in the url of the browser I obtain the right JSON.

I read a lot of question in Stackoverflow but I'm not able to resolve it.

Could you help me, please?
Thank you :)

Comment: Which version of typeahead are you using?

Comment: never in the last 15 versions of typeahead did it have a `remote` attribute. I think you have to use `bloodhound` for that

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla now I try to use bloodhound, thank you

Comment: Nothing..the same problem, the url is never called and if I use local instead of remote, it works. I don't understand what happens :(

Comment: I think that because same origin policy. your php and js script should on same domain.